# Как преобразовать однострочный XML в читаемый (многострочный и с отступами) вид?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, файлы, парсер

Есть файл .gpx (XML), который написан в одну строку.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" creator="Walkhighlands"><metadata><desc>GPX file from Walkhighlands; file is copyright Walkhighlands and must not be publicly shared on other websites. Do not remove this notice.</desc><copyright author="Walkhighlands"><year>2019</year></copyright></metadata><rte><name>Schiehallion</name><rtept lat="56.6758328268945" lon="-4.03601769647726"><ele>351.247702398777</ele><name>SCH 001</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6753865835736" lon="-4.03583038137853"><ele>344.690721458414</ele><name>SCH 002</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6735618299578" lon="-4.03614000315429"><ele>349.066837113628</ele><name>SCH 003</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6726922276694" lon="-4.03711323311608"><ele>352.76479861559</ele><name>SCH 004</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6708156570976" lon="-4.03921535478461"><ele>358.078238232484</ele><name>SCH 005</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.668930361342" lon="-4.04184722532733"><ele>371.315914270806</ele><name>SCH 006</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.668213511889" lon="-4.04446052766014"><ele>372.334546538997</ele><name>SCH 007</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6682858833434" lon="-4.04552528394144"><ele>398.610199355698</ele><name>SCH 008</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6678413316366" lon="-4.04660281552745"><ele>439.24188764472</ele><name>SCH 009</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6661616045966" lon="-4.04765411258453"><ele>430.695575764036</ele><name>SCH 010</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6661461800892" lon="-4.04859165516911"><ele>480.027087805891</ele><name>SCH 011</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6661682564118" lon="-4.04998002402942"><ele>510.264411767554</ele><name>SCH 012</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6652399416136" lon="-4.05041918562081"><ele>510.050460809779</ele><name>SCH 013</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6647376925656" lon="-4.05226859370801"><ele>532.231970017433</ele><name>SCH 014</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6650414290397" lon="-4.0542842076448"><ele>574.865789777923</ele><name>SCH 015</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6654239126298" lon="-4.05561057219045"><ele>579.359519856358</ele><name>SCH 016</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6655323240078" lon="-4.05720761852072"><ele>596.375418367434</ele><name>SCH 017</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6647987798379" lon="-4.05945231429954"><ele>641.758549734402</ele><name>SCH 018</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6648404813131" lon="-4.06100490639477"><ele>665.557786155796</ele><name>SCH 019</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6639578590415" lon="-4.06275177865564"><ele>688.314917466211</ele><name>SCH 020</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6639178489245" lon="-4.06381031031149"><ele>672.699645894647</ele><name>SCH 021</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6640682068479" lon="-4.0642265010295"><ele>721.036519969464</ele><name>SCH 022</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6636317367161" lon="-4.0661608680014"><ele>716.22166879406</ele><name>SCH 023</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6635678988414" lon="-4.06729967594798"><ele>741.202770557213</ele><name>SCH 024</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6645325456174" lon="-4.07008594317652"><ele>784.624395685673</ele><name>SCH 025</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6646271433996" lon="-4.07115187088159"><ele>814.345287170172</ele><name>SCH 026</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6648863100754" lon="-4.07177806089648"><ele>812.854262942982</ele><name>SCH 027</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6653774369754" lon="-4.07331456263909"><ele>842.076945524597</ele><name>SCH 028</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6656332229853" lon="-4.07549094973673"><ele>884.141553356552</ele><name>SCH 029</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6654706790411" lon="-4.07715475708222"><ele>893.709917627287</ele><name>SCH 030</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6658433607951" lon="-4.0803983938441"><ele>919.154672416192</ele><name>SCH 031</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6657085935658" lon="-4.08308369800892"><ele>926.544632324767</ele><name>SCH 032</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6656913596524" lon="-4.08679545454817"><ele>939.58383552022</ele><name>SCH 033</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6656592305536" lon="-4.08871123027875"><ele>970.04301422286</ele><name>SCH 034</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6654891203157" lon="-4.08947699433228"><ele>956.86801422286</ele><name>SCH 035</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6655907727544" lon="-4.09278733564568"><ele>984.63551507616</ele><name>SCH 036</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6654648415451" lon="-4.09359632994024"><ele>972.328711188507</ele><name>SCH 037</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6657530084886" lon="-4.09516268121721"><ele>989.414691911125</ele><name>SCH 038</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6661261281559" lon="-4.09701937330206"><ele>993.97252737484</ele><name>SCH 039</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.666583500041" lon="-4.09920718895852"><ele>1013.43101768389</ele><name>SCH 040</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6668895070955" lon="-4.10013813805868"><ele>1018.44797226362</ele><name>SCH 041</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6665747421354" lon="-4.09919364584093"><ele>1013.0450176837</ele><name>SCH 042</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6661293622529" lon="-4.09704076876584"><ele>993.896527374649</ele><name>SCH 043</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.665744414777" lon="-4.09513935667372"><ele>989.088691910934</ele><name>SCH 044</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6654684327018" lon="-4.09359652912738"><ele>972.560711188126</ele><name>SCH 045</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6655899846037" lon="-4.09278076411384"><ele>984.603515075874</ele><name>SCH 046</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6654874068318" lon="-4.08947200362192"><ele>956.827014222622</ele><name>SCH 047</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6656509315738" lon="-4.08872382671289"><ele>969.57901422267</ele><name>SCH 048</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6656839627926" lon="-4.0867542466085"><ele>939.574835520077</ele><name>SCH 049</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6657100915772" lon="-4.08304787757306"><ele>926.679632324648</ele><name>SCH 050</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6658488306812" lon="-4.08033994461078"><ele>918.622139986992</ele><name>SCH 051</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6654564502891" lon="-4.07714581434348"><ele>893.052917627048</ele><name>SCH 052</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6656362146319" lon="-4.07541930829843"><ele>862.861917570716</ele><name>SCH 053</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.66539109407" lon="-4.07330388920503"><ele>841.882945524597</ele><name>SCH 054</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.66488500289" lon="-4.07174861460556"><ele>813.230262942934</ele><name>SCH 055</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6646431682058" lon="-4.07116090969098"><ele>815.220287169933</ele><name>SCH 056</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6645318918242" lon="-4.0700712201935"><ele>784.524395685655</ele><name>SCH 057</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6635714359081" lon="-4.0673031333756"><ele>741.412770556927</ele><name>SCH 058</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6636194380499" lon="-4.0661438762168"><ele>716.03566879406</ele><name>SCH 059</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6640754433675" lon="-4.0642236329916"><ele>721.338519969225</ele><name>SCH 060</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6639243498078" lon="-4.06379761073934"><ele>672.347645894718</ele><name>SCH 061</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6639699420457" lon="-4.06278181269763"><ele>689.470917465973</ele><name>SCH 062</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6648409671923" lon="-4.06097555849278"><ele>665.125786155653</ele><name>SCH 063</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6648155145236" lon="-4.05947281026543"><ele>642.711549734163</ele><name>SCH 064</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6655432055018" lon="-4.05720168380928"><ele>596.175418367481</ele><name>SCH 065</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6654471749405" lon="-4.05561673483686"><ele>578.804519856453</ele><name>SCH 066</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6650316507914" lon="-4.05422329450664"><ele>574.06178977778</ele><name>SCH 067</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6647481060832" lon="-4.05223652177122"><ele>531.693970017505</ele><name>SCH 068</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6652459193012" lon="-4.05038360795913"><ele>510.460460809946</ele><name>SCH 069</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6661662610513" lon="-4.04993748455135"><ele>511.071411767769</ele><name>SCH 070</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6661524647914" lon="-4.04859199626553"><ele>479.747087806082</ele><name>SCH 071</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6661683452242" lon="-4.04762673485601"><ele>429.854575764227</ele><name>SCH 072</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6678603197906" lon="-4.04659568496954"><ele>439.490887644589</ele><name>SCH 073</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6682959867437" lon="-4.04545728516469"><ele>397.362199355793</ele><name>SCH 074</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6682195414525" lon="-4.04442168501949"><ele>372.610546539092</ele><name>SCH 075</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6689449136366" lon="-4.0418365880427"><ele>371.24191427086</ele><name>SCH 076</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.670828333406" lon="-4.0392095110979"><ele>358.046238232514</ele><name>SCH 077</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6735601676694" lon="-4.03613175205858"><ele>349.065837113637</ele><name>SCH 078</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.6753837567767" lon="-4.03583839065357"><ele>344.720721458378</ele><name>SCH 079</name></rtept><rtept lat="56.675826302125" lon="-4.03603203579921"><ele>351.061702398706</ele><name>SCH 080</name></rtept></rte></gpx>
```

Задача: систематизировать этот файл посредством разделения на строки. Но разделение должно быть по определенным словам. И в результате получить:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" creator="Walkhighlands">
<metadata>
    <desc>GPX file from Walkhighlands; file is copyright Walkhighlands and must not be publicly shared on other websites. Do not remove this notice.</desc>
    <copyright author="Walkhighlands"><year>2019</year></copyright>
</metadata>
<rte>
<name>Schiehallion</name>
<rtept lat="56.6758328268945" lon="-4.03601769647726"><ele>351.247702398777</ele><name>SCH 001</name></rtept>
<rtept lat="56.6753865835736" lon="-4.03583038137853"><ele>344.690721458414</ele><name>SCH 002</name></rtept>
<rtept lat="56.6735618299578" lon="-4.03614000315429"><ele>349.066837113628</ele><name>SCH 003</name></rtept>
<rtept lat="56.6726922276694" lon="-4.03711323311608"><ele>352.76479861559</ele><name>SCH 004</name></rtept>
<rtept lat="56.6708156570976" lon="-4.03921535478461"><ele>358.078238232484</ele><name>SCH 005</name></rtept>
...
</rte>
</gpx>
```

Как я могу реализовать такой скрипт?

Была попытка реализации в таком виде:

```py
with open('1-2-3.gpx', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
    with open('123.gpx', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        xml = file.read().replace(' ?>', ' ?>\n')
        out.write(xml)
        gpxx = file.read().replace(' xmlns:gpxx', '\nxmlns:gpxx')
        out.write(gpxx)
        metadata = file.read().replace('<metadata>', '\n<metadata>\n')
        out.write(metadata)
        link = file.read().replace('</link>', '</link>\n')
        out.write(link)
        time = file.read().replace('</time>', '</time>\n')
        out.write(time)
        cl_metadata = file.read().replace('</metadata>', '</metadata>\n')
        out.write(cl_metadata)
        trk = file.read().replace('<trk>', '<trk>\n')
        out.write(trk)
        name = file.read().replace('</name>', '</name>\n')
        out.write(name)
        extensions = file.read().replace('</extensions>', '</extensions>\n')
        out.write(extensions)
        trkseg = file.read().replace('<trkseg>', '<trkseg>\n')
        out.write(trkseg)
        trkpt = file.read().replace('</trkpt>', '</trkpt>\n')
        out.write(trkpt)
        cl_trkseg = file.read().replace('</trkseg>', '</trkseg>\n')
        out.write(cl_trkseg)
        cl_trk = file.read().replace('</trk>', '</trk>\n')
        out.write(cl_trk)
```

Но этот бред не дает никакого результата.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример __валидного__ XML?

Comment: @MaxU, простите недопонимаю вопроса... вложить/вставить в вопрос исходник XML?

Comment: если вы хотите работающий пример, то нужен такой XML, который можно пропарсить без ошибок. Проверить XML можно здесь: https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Решение (с) Ben Noland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206856/5741205):

```
import xml.dom.minidom

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xml_fname) # or xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)
pretty_xml_as_string = dom.toprettyxml()
```

---

Пример:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

def beautify_xml(xml_str):
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_str)
    return dom.toprettyxml()

with open(r"C:\temp\sample.gpx") as fin:
    data = fin.read()

with open(r"C:\temp\sample_pretty.gpx", "wt") as fout:
    fout.write(beautify_xml(data))
```

---

Результат:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3">
    <metadata>
        <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
            <text>Garmin International</text>
        </link>
        <time>2019-07-01T09:48:21Z</time>
    </metadata>
    <trk>
        <name>2019-06-29 11:53:47 День</name>
        <extensions>
            <gpxx:TrackExtension>
                <gpxx:DisplayColor>Red</gpxx:DisplayColor>
            </gpxx:TrackExtension>
        </extensions>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="54.3596829381" lon="26.9965665042">
                <ele>162.23</ele>
                <time>2019-06-29T08:53:47Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="54.3597932439" lon="26.9962674379">
                <ele>163.45</ele>
                <time>2019-06-29T08:53:50Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="54.3598700222" lon="26.9960754924">
                <ele>165.52</ele>
                <time>2019-06-29T08:53:52Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="54.3600389175" lon="26.9958708063">
                <ele>168.84</ele>
                <time>2019-06-29T08:53:55Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="54.3600928131" lon="26.9957964588">
                <ele>171.05</ele>
                <time>2019-06-29T08:53:56Z</time>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```